# XAMPP Tomcat Version

Tags: tomcat, xampp

How do I figure out what version of tomcat my xampp is running ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found:

> You should be able to find this in the
>   log called '**catalina.out**'.
>   Alternatively, you can go right to the
>   source; open
>   **$TOMCAT_HOME/server/lib/catalina.jar**
>   in a tool capable of handling zip or
>   jar files, and read the file called
>   org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties.
>
> That last bit is not guaranteed to
>   work across multiple versions, though.

Personal opinion -- the catalina solution should be perfectly fine.

P.S. your (XAMPP) Tomcat home folder usually lies in $XAMPP/tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just start the tomcat in xampp and press admin button or navigate to localhost:8080 in browser and the tomcat homepage will show up with version details and documentation.